# Is this possible or am I just seeing things?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, 802.11

I was just playing around in the properties section of my student accommodation's 5ghz wifi network and upon scrolling down in MS settings where it describes the specs of the network I realized that the accommodation's router uses the 802.11a wifi standard all the way from 1999 is that possible in 2023?

Answer (score 1):

The question is, was your OS telling you that the AP’s 5GHz radio *only* supports 802.11a, or was it telling you that it supports 802.11a along with 802.11n, and maybe 802.11ac, and maybe even 802.11ax? If it was just telling you the AP’s 5GHz radio supports all the 5GHz Wi-Fi technology generations all the way back to 802.11a, then it’s no surprise at all. All Wi-Fi chipsets support all the earlier Wi-Fi flavors for each band they support. That means any Wi-Fi chipset that supports AX (Wi-Fi 6) in 2.4GHz also supports N, G, B, and even the DSSS flavor of the original 802.11 standard from 1997. And any Wi-Fi chipset that supports AX in the 5GHz band also supports AC, N, and A.

Even if your OS was telling you that the AP’s 5GHz radio only supported 802.11a, it’s not *too* surprising. 802.11a didn’t really hit the market until 2002, and it was the only 5GHz Wi-Fi technology until N came out in 2007. So it’s perfectly possible that some dual-band AP got installed in that place between 2002 and 2007 or so, and it’s just stayed running all this time, and no one cared or had the budget to modernize it.

Another possibility is that the hardware is capable of, say, AC, N and A in 5GHz, but someone who didn’t know what they were doing was messing around with admin settings and accidentally told the 5GHz radio to go into A-only mode.

Comment: Can I ask smth else? I've checked the bottom of the router and it's labeled a "modem router". What does that mean? Because I can see that it's not a modem because it doesn't have an RG6 or DSL port and it's also hooked up to another device that plugs in the wall by means of RJ11. Why is it called a "modem router" if it's just a wireless router?

Comment: @garrix1032 What's the exact model of the router?

Comment: So there are 2 dsl modems, one of which is the dsl modem/router combo it's really a modem because I realised it has a dsl port but it's still not used because it also has a WAN port and the other one is an old dsl modem with some old phone cable that connects to the wall. The modem/router combo had to be added to have a router on the network to create the LAN, add more devices and wireless capability to the network and to speed up the network. The old modem is only needed because the wall jack is old and only accepts the phone cable of the dsl modem. the combo device is only used as a router

Comment: I overlooked the dsl port because it wasn't plugged in. The WAN port was instead which what you would use if you wanted to use it as a router to connect it to a dsl modem that brings in the internet through the electrical lines outside @Peregrino69

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. It's a compatible protocol after all and the frequency seems right too. AFAIK all wifi devices are backwards compatible but speeds and links will be capped to the latest protocol supported.

This question is too broad but I think a couple of things could be happening.

First, most places don't keep up with bleeding edge technology and they keep working with old routers because "They have always work right". A student accommodation seems like a place were they change technology once device stops working.

Second, it could be a setup thing but you should have already check those I supposed. To be sure get a hold or the SKU or serial number and check the specs of the device.

Or it could be a really cheap device giving the wrong information.